# PHP script does not work in a specific order

Tags: php

I have a simple HTML code that displays an image using a link to a PHP script shown below. Upon loading the HTML page, I want to display the image in the browser and send an email to a specific email addess.

The PHP script listed below is working fine as intended. However, when I move the  "Show image in browser client" code from the top to the bottom of the script, the program sends only the email and does not return the image to the HTML page. Can somone tell me why is this happening and how I can fix it.

HTML page code:

```
<body>

<img src="http://www.inoxel.com/test/image&email.php >

</body>
```

**image&email.php PHP script file that works:**

```
<?php
  
  // Show image in browser client.

   $logo = "http://www.Inoxel.com/test/happy_face2.gif"; // Set image Full Path

   readfile($logo);
   
  // Send a test email.
  
    ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    $from = "abc@efg.com";
    $to = "def@pac.net";
    $subject = "PHP Mail Test script";
    $message = "This is a test to check the PHP Mail functionality";
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    mail($to,$subject,$message, $headers);
    echo "Test email sent";
  
?>
```

**image&email.php PHP script file that does not work:**

```
<?php

  // Send a test email.
  
    ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    $from = "abc@efg.com";
    $to = "def@pac.net";
    $subject = "PHP Mail Test script";
    $message = "This is a test to check the PHP Mail functionality";
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    mail($to,$subject,$message, $headers);
    echo "Test email sent";
    
  // Show image in browser client.

   $logo = "http://www.Inoxel.com/test/happy_face2.gif"; // Set image Full Path

   readfile($logo);
   
?>
```

Comment: try using an absolute path on your image

Answer (score 2):

You are using `echo` before `readfile`, which does not work.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works. Can I use a different method to pass the image instead of using readfile()

Comment: You cannot output text and an image. Choose one.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this line for a second:

```
echo "Test email sent";
```

Your browser will attempt to parse this text as part of the image and fails miserably. Therefore you shouldn't output any text if you plan to show the image through `readfile()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works. Can I use a different method to pass the image instead readfile()

Answer (score 0):

The function [readfile()](http://php.net/readfile) `Reads a file and writes it to the output buffer`. When you call that function it will mimic the behaviour of a webserver when it's delivering a file from the filesystem. So echo'ing something together with that file is at the least completely useless because at it's best it will corrupt the file (because it's sending byte data and your string, which is not part of the file).

You can send a mail in the same script, that's no problem at all. But if you want to know if a mail has been sent, either write something away in your log files, or do it with a separate (xhr) request.